# Should I always use the -ised ending for UK english and the -ized for US?

Tags: american-english

Realized vs realised, randomized vs randomised etc. Is it true that the former is always correct in US and the latter in UK english? Is there a list of english-speaking nations that use the former or the latter?

Comment: By the way, British dictionaries actually prefer the -ize spellings but people on the street don't necessarily agree. It's a similar situation in Australia where I'm from.

Comment: Notably, Americans still use "use" (and not "uze"... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it depends on the origin of the word... Greek is -ized and French or Latin is -ised, but most British dictionaries says -ised is preferred as Latin derivation is more common but -ized is an accepted alternative, whereas US almost exclusively use -ized.

A lot of people prefer one over the other simply due to the way they look when written and that can change depending on style of writing or even font being used.

Answer (score 2):

In nearly all cases, yes.

-se is preferred in Australian and British English and -ze in American English.

If you were to use -ze in Commonwealth English it wouldn't be wrong, per se, but you would probably receive a few remarks about how American it is.